# how to delete all node_modules from all packages in npm 7 workspace monorepo

Tags: npm, monorepo, npm-workspaces

how can I delete all `node_modules` folders from all packages in an npm 7 workspace?

With Lerna we could just execute `lerna clean -y` but when migrating to native NPM 7+ workspaces, is there some equivalent?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can execute this to do so:

```
npm exec --workspaces -- npx rimraf node_modules && npx rimraf node_modules
```

explanation:

- `npm exec` will execute whatever comes next
- `--workspaces` will execute it in all your packages in your monorepo
- `--` means "here comes the command to execute"
- `npx rimraf node_modules` is the command that's executed in all packages: it means it will delete the `node_modules` folder
- `&&` means "and then"
- `npx rimraf node_modules` is executed again so the root folder `node_modules` also get deleted

That's all! Good luck

Comment: Same for pnpm: `pnpm -r exec rm -rf node_modules`

Answer (score 4):

From this video on [How to delete node modules like a pro.](https://youtube.com/shorts/qOSH2pYg6m8?feature=share)

```
npx npkill
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this to work on version 10.2.3, without needing third party libraries.

```bash
npm exec --workspaces -c 'rm -rf node_modules'
```

Answer (score -2):

In lerna@7
Run the below command as mentioned [here](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/libs/commands/clean#readme)!

```
npx lerna clean -y
```